# In Angular, why does ng-click button fires multiple times?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-click

I have some buttons on in my app that look like this:

```
<ul class="gallery-buttons">
    <li><button class="video-gallery" ng-click="getGallery('video',{{install.id}})"></button></li>
    <li><button class="image-gallery" ng-click="getGallery('image',{{install.id}})"></button></li>
</ul>
```

my controller:

```
var nanoApp = angular.module('nanoApp', ['ngRoute', 'ngCordova']);
nanoApp
.config(function ($routeProvider, $compileProvider) {
    ...code to setup all my routes using the $routeProvider...
})
.controller('InstallationListController', ["$scope", "$cordovaSQLite", "$rootScope", function ($scope, $cordovaSQLite, $rootScope) {
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", function () {
        ...do some database calls and setup initial $scope...
        $scope.getGallery = function (galleryType, installId) {
            console.log('made it');
        }
    });

});
```

My buttons are part of a `controller` and `$scope` that has an `ng-repeat` of 41 elements. When I select one of them I get the `console.log` 41 times. Even if I move the buttons outside the `ng-repeat` so there are only one set, it still fires 41 times.

--- **EDIT** ---

info on my ng-repeat, note that this is from my template pulled in my `$routeProvier.when` and the controller is declared there and not on the container:

```
<div id="installationlist" class="container">

    <div class="install" section-width directive-scroll-to="{{moveframe}}" get-products install-index="{{$index}}" ng-repeat="install in installations track by $index">
        <div class="details">
            <div class="text">
                <div class="text-container">

                    <p class="industry">Industry: {{install.industry}}</p>
                    <p class="title">{{install.name}}</p>

                    <p class="location">{{install.location}}</p>

                    <div class="product-block">
                        <p class="product" ng-repeat="product in install.products track by $index">{{product.name}}</p>
                        <p class="pixelPitch" ng-if="install.pixelPitch != null">{{install.pixelPitch}}</p>
                    </div>

                    <p class="desc">{{install.instText}}</p>

                </div>
            </div>

            <ul class="gallery-buttons">
                <li><button class="video-gallery" ng-click="getGallery('video',install.id)"></button></li>
                <li><button class="image-gallery" ng-click="getGallery('image',install.id)"></button></li>
            </ul>
        </div>

        <div class="image" style="background-image:url('img/products/nanoslim-bkg.jpg')"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: I think you should add the `cordova` tag for a possible answer, at first glance there is no error. The error may be occurring in the so-called `deviceready`

Comment: i just tried it outside the `deviceready`, same issue. The `ngCordova` plugin is just a connection that allows me to use `angular` and the `cordova-sqlite-store` plugin. I'll post a code snippet of my ng-repeat.

Comment: @NickBorisenko - thanks for the link but it doesn't seem to fit my issue. Am I just not seeing the coloration?

Comment: If I remove all the repeating, it only fires once so it is an issue I'm having with `ng-repeat` in some way.

Comment: the repeat has directives that use the controller? I mean to `section-width, directive-scroll-to, get-products, install-index`

Comment: `section-width` is what calculates and sets the width of sections on my views so a swipe function works based on screen size, `directive-scroll-to` is a value passed to the `screen-size` directive so the section can be placed at the correct "frame" when loaded, `get-products` add to the `$scope` the list of products for each item repeated, and `install-index` is a value passed to `get-products` so the directive knows which products to get for each item repeated.

Comment: I tried removing `ng-repeat` and assigning a `directive` to it while binding a `click event` (element.bind("click", function (e) {...});`) and it still fired 41 times.

Comment: Try creating a plnkr to replicate the issue. btw side note: You do not interpolate (`{{`) in ng-click argument expression @ `{{install.id}}`

Comment: I'll try to set a plnkr up. All my data is pulled from a database so it will take a sec to replicate. Thanks, yeah I fixed that issue. For got to recopy and paste.

Comment: the plnkr only runs once... :::groan:::

Comment: Here's the plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/5GAr5yHb6WVUARrkSx20?p=preview

Comment: @wZVanG - I just found out if I remove `section-width directive-scroll-to="{{moveframe}}"` from the top `ng-repeat` it runs once not 41 times...

Comment: Yes, some of these directives are calling the controller again, check it

Comment: I'm using a js plugin to do some scrolling pieces. If I remove that from the `section-width` directive the problem goes away. I created a directive and placed it in a spot outside the loop (in `<div id="installationlist" class="container">`) the plugin doesn't run because the `class="install"` elements haven't loaded.

Comment: since a `section-width` will always go along with my plugin but I need the repeat to finish before run the plugin method, how can I have the it run after the ng-repeat finishes?!?!

Comment: I'd like to run my `ng-repeat` then run a single directive that sets the width and the scroll plugin. Again, I need to this happen AFTER the `ng-repeat` has completed.

Comment: I got it working using `scope.$last` and `$timeout`. I'll post my solution/answer after I finish this beer.